# Content View not created error

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I am trying to instantiate a list view by downloading images from a server and then in onPostExecute() of my asynkTask class I call setImages() that is in my main activity. After mTransaction.commit() it crashes and I get the error message "content View not yet created"

Here is my setImages Method:

```
public void setImages(List<Bitmap> result)
{
    log("Entered setImages()");

    ListViewAdapter listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,       R.id.imageView, result);
    customListFragment = new customListFragment();
    customListFragment.setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    FragmentTransaction mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mTransaction.add(R.layout.activity_main, customListLineFragment);
    mTransaction.commit();

}
```

And here is my logcat:

```
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623): Process: com.example.test, PID: 2623
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:386)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.ListFragment.setEmptyText(ListFragment.java:290)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at com.example.test.listFragment.onAttach(listFragment.java:28)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-02 16:10:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(2623):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the CustomListFragment Class

```
public class CustomListFragment extends ListFragment {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    this.setEmptyText("....");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the adapter after adding the fragment and the commit.
Try this:

```
mTransaction.commit();
mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
customListFragment.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: I still get the crash and the error message "content view not yet created". Should I possibly be adding the fragment view before I download the data?

Comment: Can you post your customListFragment onAttach and onCreateView methods?